# poll() with non blocking udp socket

Tags: c++, sockets, udp

I am trying to make a c++ program work which is written by somebody else. I am having hard time understanding it. I am not even %100 sure that we can use poll() with a UDP socket but the code I am refactoring, is using poll() to read from udp socket  as follows:

```
fd.fd = m_bsocket;
fd.events = POLLIN;


iPollResult = poll(&fd, 1, iTimeout);

if(iPollResult > 0)
{
    int iReceivedByteCount = recv(m_bsocket, p_pBuffer, p_iBufferSize, 0);
    if(iReceivedByteCount > 0)
    {
        *p_pReadSize = iReceivedByteCount;
    }
    else
    {
        eReturnValue = UDP_READ_ERROR;
    }
}

return eReturnValue;
```

I tried sending udp packets to this program using command line:

echo "123" | nc -u 127.0.0.1 25

It looks like poll() always times out and returns 0, therefore I can not read anything.

I also wrote a small c# program that sends udp datagram, but I can not receive the message. I am wondering what I am doing wrong...

Comment: sorry for not including, 1000 ms. I also tried making it 10000 ms, it didn't help. maybe I am creating socket in a wrong way.

Comment: If this is unix, see if netstat and tcpdump can give more information.  Similar tools exist for windows.

Comment: when I run netstat -lu , I don't see anything that listens on my port 25, is it because I am using poll() or is something else likely to be screwed?

Comment: Is the socket a connected (i.e. created using `accept` or `connect`) or unconnected? Although it shouldn't matter, as a UDP socket should be "pollable" no matter if it's connected or unconnected.

Comment: socket is connected. It is created using connect. It has socket no of 3. I have one question though, when I create it using connect, which ip address should I use in the sockaddr_in structure? Since I am listening for a datagram, should I assign 127.0.0.1? Should I assign IP address of the pc which sends the datagram?

Comment: btw every time I run netstat -s, udp packets to unknown port count increments.

Comment: If you are connecting to a host, the `sockaddr_in` in the `connect` call should be initialized the host address/port of the host you are connecting to. Can you add the `connect` call, and other initialization of the socket, to your question?

Comment: you don't need to `connect()` (UDP is connectionless) you need to `bind()` the socket to the IP of the interface you are listening on or `0.0.0.0` for all interfaces. And when sending to a destination, use `sendto()`

Comment: @joachim in this context, since my program is listening for data, my program is considered to be host, is that correct? So I should assign my host IP address to sockaddr_in, btw I already tried both  of the IP addresses in socket creation(host and client), neither worked.

Comment: Please post a minimal complete compilable program.

Comment: thank you guys, using bind instead of connect fixed my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While UDP sockets can be used to connect to another host, they are mostly used "connectionless". Reading your question and comments it makes no sense that you have a connected socket. Instead it should be connectionless as suggested by WouterH in his comment.

```
int sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);

struct sockaddr_in sin = { 0 };
sin.sin_family = AF_INET;
sin.sin_port = htons(25);
sin.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &sin, sizeof(sin));

// Make socket non-blocking if needed
```

With the above code, whenever someone sends UDP packets to port 25 on any address of your host, your socket will intercept it. Use e.g. `poll` or `select` to know when data is available.

Comment: I totally agree, that solves my problem, I guess it would be way easier if I wrote my udpcommunication class from the scratch:)

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to call `connect()` as UDP is connectionless. You need to `bind()` the socket to the IP of the interface you are listening on or 0.0.0.0 (`INADDR_ANY`) for all interfaces. And when sending to a destination, use `sendto()`.

For completeness: if you call `connect()` on a UDP socket, you are just setting a default destination for the `send()` function (then you can use send instead of sendto).

If you want to receive data, you always have to `bind()` the socket to the interface, or all interfaces. Beware that you will have to verify the source address from the messages you are receiving. So you might want to filter the sender by using `recvfrom()` and checking the source address.

Comment: Calling `connect` on a UDP socket does more than set a default destination. For example, it causes all inbound datagrams from any other source to be dropped.